# determine url parameter in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel an have a question.
I have controller named `ReportsArchiveController`
and function named `loadReport` in it.
this is what the method get

```
public static function loadReport(Request $request, $id, $view = 'reports.archive.single', $user_id = null)
```

this is the rout:

```
Route::get('/archive/{id}', ['as' => 'reports.archive.view', 'uses' => 'ReportsArchiveController@loadReport']);
```

I want to create new route that will use this method, and ask from where the user entered.

```
Route::get('/archive/{id}/csv', ['as' => 'reports.archive.view', 'uses' => 'ReportsArchiveController@loadReport']);
```

and ask in the method `load report` if the url is `from /archive/{id}/csv` or from `/archive/{id}`.

what I should add to the loadreport method to know if the user is from the url with csv or without? what to add to the method parameters?
using Laravel 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get url from request and check it

**script**

```
$request->url();
```

For more information:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#request-path-and-method